# Is there any better way to debug and develop when using iOS app embed AngularJS web

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, xcode

I recently need to support a project which is an iOS app running on iPad, and it uses iOS + AngularJS. Basically, it is an iOS app, however, it uses WebView to embed another AngularJS web. In AngularJS web, it has lots of html and javascript files. If I want to debug or modify some files with angularjs web, I have to use XCode and run the iOS app. By the way, I am a frontend developer, so I don't anything about iOS or XCode.

When starting the iOS app, XCode will create a folder to put my angularjs web files. The problem is when I rebuild the iOS app every time, XCode always creates **another new folder** to put my angularjs web files. This causes me a lot of efforts when developing my angularJs web, because every time when I modify my web files, I have to rebuild and restart XCode again, and I have to find the new folder which XCode created in order to find my web files. If there is anything wrong, I have to fix js files again and rebuild XCode again. This is really not a good way to develop.

**Is there any way to setup XCode to use the same folder?** At least I don't need to look for my web files when I rebuild XCode.

and

**Is it possible I don't need to rebuild XCode when I modify web files?** If I modify js, I have to rebuild, otherwise, it won't work.

[XCode create a folder to put web files every time when I rebuild it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGUJV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode is creating a a bundle that can be installed on devices.

If you wish to debug without rerunning, you need to set up a development environment and load the files from there, rather than load from inside the bundle.

Depending on your needs, you could simply load files from a hardcoded path on your local Mac. This will only work on the simulator and is not recommended, because if you have more than one developer, the paths may not match between developer machines. A better solution is to run a local web server and load your web view from that local server.